# Day Month extraction pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

so recently I was doing a project where I need it to extract day and month together from a date in a dataframe in **python** without the year, I ended up doing by manipulating string, but I was wondering if there is a quicker way to do it using the pandas and datetime librairie , only day and month together without the year

**Example :** `2012-05-27 —> 05-27`

Comment: Pandas has excellant documentation [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html). .. [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2012-05-27', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%m-%d")
```